# How do I do a WHERE clause on a COUNT in Cypher?

Tags: cypher

This is what I'm trying:

```
match 
(e:Person) - [r] - (f:Person) 
where (count(r) > 5 AND count (r) <10) 
return id(e), e.name;
```

I get

```
QueryExecutionKernelException: Invalid use of aggregating function count(...) in this context
```

Basically I'm wanting to find a Person who is related to between 5 and 10 other Persons.

Comment: Do you mean that this person can be connected to the same other person by more than one relationship ?   ie. (joe)-[:likes]-(moe),  (joe)-[:friends]-(moe) and (joe)-[:neighbors]-(moe)
or do you mean joe connected to jim connected to mark connected to moe?

Comment: Oh, yeah I'm wanting to count the different number of friends. ie. joe likes moe and joe friends moe should be just one relative. So while this query doesn't reflect this, there's still the issue of the syntax error which is more moot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

to find out people who are connected with each other by more than relationship
ex:

- a likes b
- a knows b
- a lives_with b

**use**

```
match (a:Person)-[r]-(b:person)
with a,b,count(r) as cnt
where cnt > 5 and cnt < 10
return *
```

if however you want to find people who are connected as a chain ( friends of friends )

- a knows b
- b knows c
- c likes d
- d knows e

and you want to find a to d  then you can use something like

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[r*1..3]->(m:Person)
RETURN *
```

relevant tutorial [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-finding-paths.html)

Comment: Binding relationships to a list in a variable length pattern is deprecated. (org.neo4j.graphdb.impl.notification.NotificationDetail$Factory$2@146a7705)